# Getting MetaData from MP3 radio stream using NAudio

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio

After searching in the internet and in Stackoverflow ! i didn't find any tutorial or example which explain getting Metadata from a radio stream using Naudio !

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

NAudio can't do that. Radio Streams often use special "formats" like Shoutcast, which NAudio can't parse. You have to find out which other "formats" are out there and implement a parser yourself. You can find an example for shoutcast here:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548943/Shoutcast-Internet-radio-protocol
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19125/ShoutcastStream-Class

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! i have found the source code on CodeProject:codeproject.com/Articles/11308/SHOUTcast-Stream-Ripper very useful ,it can record and parse a radio stream ! my problem is how to convert the MP3 stream and play it while recording !

Comment: I tried to combine the code source on code project and a source code done by Nadio it works ! but it retrives only the metadata of the first song ! if you want i can give you a link to download it and try it ! thanks again for your help !

Comment: Well. As far as I know, NAudio parses the stream for MP3 Frames. The rest of data gets truncated. You would have to constantly check for Shoudcast frames between the MP3 frames.